# Standard deviation plot in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create sd plot but really can't do this. What am I doing wrong?

```
    data_iris %>%
      mutate(st_dev = sd(Petal.Length)) %>%

      ggplot(., aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Length)) + 
      geom_line() +
      geom_point()+
      geom_errorbar(aes(x = Species, ymin=Petal.Length-sd, ymax=Petal.Length+sd), width=.2,
                    position=position_dodge(0.05))
```

What I got in repsonse is error which goes like: sth is wrong with

> Petal.Length - sd

Comment: It looks like your column is called "st_dev" not "sd". If you use "Petal.Length - st_dev", you will get a plot. Not sure that is what you want though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data(iris)
data_iris <- iris
data_iris %>%
      mutate(st_dev = sd(Petal.Length)) %>%

      ggplot(., aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Length)) + 
      geom_line() +
      geom_point()+
      geom_errorbar(aes(x = Species, ymin=Petal.Length-st_dev, ymax=Petal.Length+st_dev), width=.2,
                    position=position_dodge(0.05))
```